# C#.NET: Read CSV using % converter

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm reading a CSV file

```
Name,Score
Pat,99%
Chris,87%
```

and would like to discard the percent sign when the file is read through FileHelpers

```
using FileHelpers;

public class PctConverter : ConverterBase
{
    private NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();

    public PctConverter()
    {
        nfi.PercentSymbol = "%";
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        return decimal.Parse(from, NumberStyles.Percent, nfi);
    }
}

[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst]
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Score { get; set; }
}

var student_file = "students.csv";
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Student>();
engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
List<Student> students = engine.ReadFileAsList(student_file);
ErrorInfo[] readingErrors = engine.ErrorManager.Errors;
```

But my converter is not quite right. Can you suggest why?

Comment: What does it currently do?

Comment: Better you talke a default, completly initialized NumberFormatInfo, like from CurrentCulture or InvariantCulture. All of them use % as PercentSymbol. Do you want it consider a bad format, if the percent sign is missing ? Should "10" raise an exception ? Numberstyles.Percent doesn't exist, doesn't the compiler tell you that ? Is this what you mean with "not quiet right" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the converter on the field you want converted, also your converter didn't work for me so I simplified it a bit:

```
public class PctConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        return decimal.Parse(from.Replace("%", ""));
    }
}

[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst]
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FieldConverter(typeof(PctConverter))]
    public decimal Score { get; set; }
}
```